# How we can add wooCommerce product detail page visitor counter?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a visitor counter into my product detail page. I try to find a lot but not able to get any good solutions on the internet. Can anyone please let me know how we can add a visitor counter into our woo commerce product page? So our user can see how many people visit this product. I really appreciate this. Advance Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-visit-counter/], it gives the visitors count for each page/post. For your requirement set post type as product in the plugin settings. Then you will get the individual visitors count for each product in product detail page.